# Is there a way to place the modules on specific coordinates?

Tags: bifacial-radiance

I have been experimenting and getting used to bifacial_radiance and I was wondering if it was possible to place the modules on user provided positions instead of evenly arranged. This way, instead of having them arranged at a specific distance from each other, one could, for example, provide coordinates for each module in the scene and recreate a specific configuration of trackers.

Thank you!

Comment: For now I am trying to use the method of adding multiple scene objects adding the parameter 'originx' and 'originy' to their sceneDict. However, as I am using tracking modules instead of fixed-tilt ones, I am getting multiple different scenes, one for each angle for each module. (Plotting 3 modules in 6 positions results in 18 .rad files instead of 6, in each file there is only one module and I would like to have the three of them)